# How to architect in-memory processing for real time trading order status in Java

Tags: java, mysql, in-memory-database, complex-event-processing, in-memory-data-grid

We have an application preparing trade orders sending them to the broker(Interactive Brokers) through their API
The Application uses MySQL as a data store and ActiveMQ for processing trade order status messages from Interactive Brokers API

We store all order related data and sending notifications and order positions and order sequences data in the database, which is really taking considerable time due to database query latency

We have an issue with a performance for submitting and processing more than 200 orders and it is taking about 3-4minutes
We profiled application (JProfiler) and found to be database calls only contributing more time towards overall order execution time

As it is a trading application 3-4 minutes is a huge time as trade prices change very quickly in the market.

Please provide some in-memory frameworks or databases where we could process everything on fly and sync with the actual database at later point. (preferably MySQL as a connector)

Also, Interactive Brokers will send order status messages as call back events, Please let us know any Complex Event Processing (CEP) frameworks in java which are in-line with in-memory frameworks.

Any help with how to architect or going about implementing such frameworks is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's technically not advisable for asking for frameworks on this site, because those types of question attract opinion-driven answers, which is not what we're after. I'm sure there are a lot of sites where you can find digests for such libraries, this is not one of them.

Comment: The question is about how to architect such an application. what ever may be the framework. I'm looking for pointers to implement better app from those who already implemented such frameworks. It's not purely about knowing only about frameworks. Not sure still if this isn't fit to this q&a my apologies!

Thanks